# How to make cloud firestore rules work on python program?

Tags: python, firebase

I written rules for my firestore documents and using admin sdk credentials, that bypasses rules.
How to make rules work on python?

Python code

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
try:
  doc_ref = db.collection('users').document('test')
  doc_ref.set({'password':'testPass','shadow':'testShadow'})
  print('success')
except:
  print('failed')
```

Firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDKs run with administrative privileges and bypass the security rules for Firestore. There is no way to change that.

If you want your code to follow the security rules, you'll have to use one of the client-side SDKs, but none exists for Python at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. Then how do I keep all data safe? If any user changed python code and executed it can easily get full wiped..

Comment: Running an Admin SDK requires that you have a credentials.json file, which contains all **private** keys for the project. So you should never ship that to anyone of your end-users. In other words: you can't create client-side Firestore apps in Python with the Admin SDK, and there is no client-side Python SDK for Firestore afaik.

Comment: Ok I understood that firestore is not usable in python when app is needed for client. Thank you